# Google sheets is not respecting IF condition in my script - why?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

iam trying to lock all cells in col "A" than contains number lower than 3 but it is locking every cell it goes by no matter the condition.
Maybe i put wrong bracket somewhere? Or is it easier way to write this?
This is my first try. Iam use to VBA in excel but this is much harder.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Rezervace');

function lockRanges() {
  //First cell to lock
  var row = 1;
  var col = 1;

  // Get last row with data in sheet
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();


  for (var i = row; i < lastrow; i++) {
    //Lock current cell

 if(sheet.getRange(row,col).getValue() < 3) 
 {      
  lockRange(row, col);
      row = row + 1;
  };

  };
}




function lockRange(row, col){
  var range = sheet.getRange(row, col);

  // Create protection object. Set description, anything you like.
  var protection = range.protect().setDescription('Protected, row ' + row);

 // Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
 // permission comes from a group, the script will throw an exception upon removing the group.
 var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
 protection.addEditor(me);
 protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
 if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
   protection.setDomainEdit(false);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your loop, `row` is added by 1 when `sheet.getRange(row, col).getValue() < 3` is `true`. In this case, `row` is grown as `1, 2, 3,,,`, and the cell is locked every `row`. I thought that your issue might be due to this.
- When `getValue` is used in a loop, the process cost will be high.

  - In this modification, at first, the values are retrieved from the column "A" and the cells are protected using the retrieved values.

When these points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function lockRanges() {
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Rezervace');
  var values = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  values.forEach(([a], i) => {
    if (a < 3) {
      var protection = sheet.getRange("A" + (i + 1)).protect().setDescription('Protected, row ' + (i + 1));
      protection.addEditor(me);
      protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
      if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
        protection.setDomainEdit(false);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

### Edit:

About your following new question in the comment,

> Not sure what went wrong with that sheet but when i made a new one its working :) Thank you very much! Is there a way to check if the cell is already locked so it doesnt lock the cell 20 times in a row? My guess was to check it with the condition <3 but my understanding of the code is not great yet ''' values.forEach(([a], i) => { if (a < 3) && (sheet.getRange("A" + (i + 1)).getDescription()='Protected, row ' + (i + 1)) '''

In this case, I think that it is required to check whether the row of column "A" is protected. For this, I updated my above script as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function lockRanges() {
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Rezervace');
  
  // Retrieve the protected rows of the column "A".
  var protectedRows = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE).reduce((ar, p) => {
    var range = p.getRange();
    if (range.getColumn() == 1) ar.push(range.getRow());
    return ar;
  }, []);
  
  // Protect the rows.
  var values = sheet.getRange("A1:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  values.forEach(([a], i) => {
    if (a < 3 && !protectedRows.includes((i + 1))) {
      var protection = sheet.getRange("A" + (i + 1)).protect().setDescription('Protected, row ' + (i + 1));
      protection.addEditor(me);
      protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
      if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
        protection.setDomainEdit(false);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

- When this script is run, at first, the protected row numbers of column "A" are retrieved. And, using the retrieved row numbers, the rows of column "A" are protected. By this, the same rows which have already been protected are not protected.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reaction. Sadly it still locking all cells no matter what is in the cell. I tried to put 1 2 3 4 5 6 into A column and it locked cells from 1 to 6. It should work but its doing its own thing.. :(

Comment: @Mra Jaromir Yerome Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About your replying, unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. When I tested my proposed script, the cells of column "A" which have a number less than 3 are locked. I deeply apologize for this. So in order to correctly replicate your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Not sure what went wrong with that sheet but when i made a new one its working :) Thank you very much! Is there a way to check if the cell is already locked so it doesnt lock the cell 20 times in a row? My guess was to check it with the condition <3 but my understanding of the code is not great yet '''                                           
values.forEach(([a], i) => { if (a < 3) && (sheet.getRange("A" + (i + 1)).getDescription()='Protected, row ' + (i + 1))  '''

Comment: @Mra Jaromir Yerome Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, I added one more modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Working like a charm :) thank you!!!